# What is wrong with this array filter call in Swift?

Tags: swift

```
var arr = [4, 5, 23, 4, 5, 2, 3]
arr.filter({
    return true
})
```

I get the error `'Int' is not a subtype of ()`. What am I doing wrong? Everything I've read seems to indicate this should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var arr = [4, 5, 23, 4, 5, 2, 3]
let arr2 = arr.filter {
    _ in
    return true
}
```

Problems with your original code:

- `filter` returns an array. If you don't capture it, nothing useful happens. Notice that I've captured it in another variable; you could also reassign to the original variable.
- If a parameter is passed into an anonymous function, you *must* capture it. You can capture it namelessly, as here, or with a name, or as `$0`, but you cannot completely ignore it; you must acknowledge it. That is what my `_ in` does.

Comment: What does the "i in" achieve?

Comment: @DougSmith Cool your jets, I haven't finished writing. Okay, now I have.

Comment: @DougSmith I've just posted a Swift tutorial; here's the section on anonymous functions: http://www.apeth.com/swiftBook/ch02.html#_anonymous_functions See especially the paragraph that starts "But note that if the anonymous function takes parameters, you must use them somehow."

Comment: Why would you submit it if you hadn't finished writing? Appreciate the link and the insight though, this helped a lot.

Comment: It was right. It just wasn't as perfect as I ultimately wanted it. :) I guess it would be for the same reason that you submitted your comment and then went back and edited it... eh?

Comment: Fair enough. Thank you again. :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to provide an index to the filter:

```
arr.filter({
    n in true
})
```